# Why validation doesn't work? Django Forms

Tags: django, forms, validation

I can't figure out why validation doesn't work in my app.

My problem is that every time I send the form in my template (**base_contact.html**), the app sends me to the **/Thanks/** view, but it's so weird, because it does even if the form in the template is empty or has several validation errors. So I think that **form.is_valid()** is not working properly in this case. These are my files:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from main.models import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
        cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']
        recipients = ['example@gmail.com']

        send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Thanks/') # Redirect after POST
else:
    form = ContactForm() # An unbound form
return render_to_response('base_contact.html', {'form': form})
```

base_contact.html

```
<div class="forms">
<table>
<form action="/Contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <tr><th><label for="id_sender">Your email:</label></th>
        <td><input class="text" type="text" name="sender" id="id_sender" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label></th>
        <td><input class="text" id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_message">Message:</label></th>
        <td><textarea class="styletextarea" name="message" id="id_message" rows="7" cols="35" /></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" /></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is the indentation for `return HttpResponseRedirect('/Thanks/')` exactly the same in your code as above? What you have posted here looks correct to me.

Comment: yes, It's the same... but It's curious, if I comment this line with #, I get all the errors in my template page. But of course the form won't be sent.

Comment: have you tried displaying the errors with an else associated to the is_valid if? and as alasdair said, try reindenting that line (delete white spaces until return is attached to sendmail's closing parenthesis then press enter (aka go to a newline).

Comment: omg, that was the problem :) Thank you very much. I'm discovering that indenting can be a big problem in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the indentation of the following line

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/Thanks/')
```

In Python (and therefore Django), indentation is very important. It is [recommended](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to use 4 spaces per indentation level. Avoid using tabs. You can often change the settings for your text editor or ide to use 4 spaces when you press the tab key.